# Accessing an object in an object in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have an Json file that looks like that

```
"timeline": [
{
"t0": [
    { "x": 0.000000, "y": 0.000000, "z": 0.000000 },
    { "x": -0.120473, "y": 4.998491, "z": 0.000000 },
    { "x": -0.323933, "y": 9.994292, "z": 0.000000 },
    { "x": -0.610325, "y": 14.986026, "z": 0.000000 },
    { "x": -0.979571, "y": 19.972315, "z": 0.000000 }, {....}
```

and so on..

So there is an object "timeline" that consists of 61 objects called "t0", "t1", ... "t60" and everyone of these is an array with points that consist of an x-, y- and z-Coordinate.

So can someone tell me how i access the t0 Object or even better the seperate Coordinates in it?

Is the json-File correct that way in general?

best regards

lxg

Comment: obj.timeline['t0'] doesn't work

Comment: `obj.timeline[0]['t0']`. My bad! Didn't see timeline is an array

Comment: completing Rajesh comment: after accessing the `t0`, you should loop it's array to get each object that contains coordinates. Remember: `timeline` and `t0` are not objects, but arrays with objects inside.

Comment: JSON is by definition a STRING and by parsing you create a JavaScript Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {"timeline": [{"t0": [{ "x": 0.000000, "y": 0.000000, "z": 0.000000 },{ "x": -0.120473, "y": 4.998491, "z": 0.000000 },{ "x": -0.323933, "y": 9.994292, "z": 0.000000 },{ "x": -0.610325, "y": 14.986026, "z": 0.000000 },{ "x": -0.979571, "y": 19.972315, "z": 0.000000 }]},{"t1": [{ "x": 0.000000, "y": 0.000000, "z": 0.000000 },{ "x": -0.120473, "y": 4.998491, "z": 0.000000 },{ "x": -0.323933, "y": 9.994292, "z": 0.000000 },{ "x": -0.610325, "y": 14.986026, "z": 0.000000 },{ "x": -0.979571, "y": 19.972315, "z": 0.000000}] }]}
```

variable data contain your sample json object.

```
let cnt = 0;
for(let obj of data.timeline){
        var str= "t"+cnt;
        for(let p of obj[str]){
            console.log("x is :"+p.x);
            console.log("y is :"+p.y);
            console.log("z is :"+p.z);
        }
        cnt=cnt+1;
}
```

using this you can extract seperate Coordinates from json data for this type of json object. if you have different type of json data then code will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple write your logic here

```
var data = {"timeline": [{"t0": [
{ "x": 0.000000, "y": 0.000000, "z": 0.000000 },
{ "x": -0.120473, "y": 4.998491, "z": 0.000000 },
{ "x": -0.323933, "y": 9.994292, "z": 0.000000 },
{ "x": -0.610325, "y": 14.986026, "z": 0.000000 },
{ "x": -0.979571, "y": 19.972315, "z": 0.000000 }
]}]}

console.log(data.timeline[0]["t0"]);
```

Or else you can try this

```
$.each(data.timeline, function(key, val) {console.log(val)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments in code showing what each thing is.  No need for a separate counter.

```js
let obj = {
  "timeline": [{
      "t0": [{
          "x": 0.000000,
          "y": 0.000000,
          "z": 0.000000
        },
        {
          "x": -0.120473,
          "y": 4.998491,
          "z": 0.000000
        },
        {
          "x": -0.323933,
          "y": 9.994292,
          "z": 0.000000
        },
        {
          "x": -0.610325,
          "y": 14.986026,
          "z": 0.000000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "t1": [{
          "x": 0.000000,
          "y": 0.000000,
          "z": 0.000000
        },
        {
          "x": -0.120473,
          "y": 4.998491,
          "z": 0.000000
        },
        {
          "x": -0.323933,
          "y": 9.994292,
          "z": 0.000000
        },
        {
          "x": -0.610325,
          "y": 14.986026,
          "z": 0.000000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "t2": [{
          "x": 0.000000,
          "y": 0.000000,
          "z": 0.000000
        },
        {
          "x": -0.120473,
          "y": 4.998491,
          "z": 0.000000
        },
        {
          "x": -0.323933,
          "y": 9.994292,
          "z": 0.000000
        },
        {
          "x": -0.610325,
          "y": 14.986026,
          "z": 0.000000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
//two different ways to access
let onepoint = obj["timeline"][1]["t1"][2]["x"]
console.log(onepoint);
let onepointDirect = obj.timeline[1].t1[2].x
console.log(onepointDirect);

// timeline array process
for (let i = 0; i < obj.timeline.length; i++) {
  // objects inside each array
  for (let tobj in obj.timeline[i]) {
    console.log("tobj", tobj); //t0,t1 etc.
    // array of objects (the x,y,z things
    for (let t = 0; t < obj.timeline[i][tobj].length; t++) {
      console.log(tobj, t, obj.timeline[i][tobj][t]);
      // each x
      console.log("x:", obj.timeline[i][tobj][t].x);
    }
  }
}
```